# mgcv: obtain predictive distribution of response given new data (negative binomial example)

Tags: r, statistics, regression, gam, mgcv

In GAM (and GLM, for that matter), we're fitting a conditional likelihood model.  So after fitting the model, for a new input `x` and response `y`, I should be able to compute the predictive probability or density of a specific value of `y` given `x`.  I might want to do this to compare the fit of various models on validation data, for example.  Is there a convenient way to do this with a fitted GAM in `mgcv`?  Otherwise, how do I figure out the exact form of the density that is used so I can plug in the parameters appropriately?

As a specific example, consider a negative binomial GAM :

```
## From ?negbin
library(mgcv)
set.seed(3)
n<-400
dat <- gamSim(1,n=n)
g <- exp(dat$f/5)

## negative binomial data... 
dat$y <- rnbinom(g,size=3,mu=g)

## fit with theta estimation...
b <- gam(y~s(x0)+s(x1)+s(x2)+s(x3),family=nb(),data=dat)
```

And now I want to compute the predictive probability of, say, `y=7`, given `x=(.1,.2,.3,.4)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. `mgcv` is doing (empirical) Bayesian estimation, so you can obtain predictive distribution. For your example, here is how.

```
# prediction on the link (with standard error)
l <- predict(b, newdata = data.frame(x0 = 0.1, x1 = 0.2, x2 = 0.3, x3 = 0.4), se.fit = TRUE)

# Under central limit theory in GLM theory, link value is normally distributed
# for negative binomial with `log` link, the response is log-normal
p.mu <- function (mu) dlnorm(mu, l[[1]], l[[2]])

# joint density of `y` and `mu`
p.y.mu <- function (y, mu) dnbinom(y, size = 3, mu = mu) * p.mu(mu)

# marginal probability (not density as negative binomial is discrete) of `y` (integrating out `mu`)
# I have carefully written this function so it can take vector input
p.y <- function (y) {
  scalar.p.y <- function (scalar.y) integrate(p.y.mu, lower = 0, upper = Inf, y = scalar.y)[[1]]
  sapply(y, scalar.p.y)
  }
```

Now since you want probability of `y = 7`, conditional on specified new data, use

```
p.y(7)
# 0.07810065
```

---

In general, this approach by numerical integration is not easy. For example, if other link functions like `sqrt()` is used for negative binomial, the distribution of response is not that straightforward (though also not difficult to derive).

Now I offer a sampling based approach, or Monte Carlo approach. This is most similar to Bayesian procedure.

```
N <- 1000  # samples size

set.seed(0)

## draw N samples from posterior of `mu`
sample.mu <- b$family$linkinv(rnorm(N, l[[1]], l[[2]]))

## draw N samples from likelihood `Pr(y|mu)`
sample.y <- rnbinom(1000, size = 3, mu = sample.mu)

## Monte Carlo estimation for `Pr(y = 7)`
mean(sample.y == 7)
# 0.076
```

---

**Remark 1**

Note that as empirical Bayes, all above methods are conditional on estimated smoothing parameters. If you want something like a "full Bayes", set `unconditional = TRUE` in `predict()`.

**Remark 2**

Perhaps some people are assuming the solution as simple as this:

```
mu <- predict(b, newdata = data.frame(x0 = 0.1, x1 = 0.2, x2 = 0.3, x3 = 0.4), type = "response")
dnbinom(7, size = 3, mu = mu)
```

Such result is conditional on regression coefficients (assumed fixed without uncertainty), thus `mu` becomes fixed and not random. This is **not** predictive distribution. Predictive distribution would integrate out uncertainty of model estimation.

Comment: Thanks for this great answer! What are your thoughts about using the bootstrap to avoid using central limit theory here?

Comment: @DavidR Sorry I don't know how bootstrap works (shame). How many data do you have? If you have lots of data then CLT is rather accurate. Confidence intervals are CLT based, aren't they? **Yeah but please, if you work out a bootstrap solution do post it as another answer. I will be the first to learn and vote up!**

Comment: Since we're estimating theta ("size") of the negative binomial, should we plug in  b$family$getTheta(TRUE) for size?

Comment: @DavidR Oh I left this unaddressed! **theta** is a hyper parameter, estimated together with smoothing parameters. So, in pure empirical Bayes point of view, yes, we should plug in this point estimate.

Comment: @DavidR Well, it now seems more reasonable to set **unconditional = TRUE** in predict(), if we want to count in the uncertainty of these hypers.

Comment: @ 李哲源 Zheyuan Li One issue with doing the Monte Carlo estimation in the way you suggest is that rare events will get probability 0.  How about averaging the likelihoods given by each sample.mu?